# Google Sheets countif criteria text contains ">" symbol

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a formula that recognizes when the text in a given cell (G15 in the example below) is any of several values. I'm currently using countif as follows (this is part of a larger formula that requires the countif output to be =0):

```
=COUNTIF({"<0.25","0.25-0.315","0.5-0.71","0.8-0.9","1.12-1.25","1.5-2","2-2.5",">2.5"},$G15)
```

However, if the value of $G15 is either "<0.25" or ">2.5" the formula fails, I think because countif interprets the ">" as an input instead of just text. I've tried using TO_TEXT and concatenating """" on either side of the offending arguments,

e.g.,

```
=COUNTIF({"<0.25","0.25-0.315","0.5-0.71","0.8-0.9","1.12-1.25","1.5-2","2-2.5",">2.5"},TO_TEXT($G55))
```

or

```
=COUNTIF({"<0.25","0.25-0.315","0.5-0.71","0.8-0.9","1.12-1.25","1.5-2","2-2.5",">2.5"},CONCAT("""",$G55,""""))
```

but it still seems to be interpreting them as countif arguments instead of just text strings. (I've also tried adding both of these to "<0.25" and ">2.5" inside the first brackets.)

Any other approaches here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*prepend `=` OR `*` to the cell value as below  & try*

```js
=COUNTIF({"<0.25","0.25-0.315","0.5-0.71","0.8-0.9","1.12-1.25","1.5-2","2-2.5",">2.5"},"="&$G16)
```